# Form validation for Textarea in comment field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a form validation for textarea. It requires users to enter a minimum characters in the comment box. If they enter less than required minimum characters, then when they hit Submit button, it shows error. The error should show the numbers of characters they already entered and the message. For example: Question #1 - You wrote n characters. Please write at least 50 characters for Question1.

Currently, I set 50 characters for minlength and 500 characters for maxlength. However, it does not work.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Questions</title>
    <style type="text/css">
textarea {
  display:block;
  margin:1em 0;
} 
</style> 
<script language="javascript">   

function lText(lField, lNum) {
 if (lField.value.length > lNum) {
  lField.value = lField.value.substring(0, lNum);
 }
}
// Check for the Form Validation
 function ckForm() {
  var charLimit = [obj.getAttribute('minlength'), obj.getAttribute('maxlength')];
  var fieldID = obj.getAttribute('id');

  var errs = 0
  var msgbox = "You forgot to answer the following question(s).\nPlease complete and re-submit the form. Thank you!\n";
  var go = msgbox
  var ctr = 0;

 var Traveler = document.getElementById("selectTraveler");
 if (Traveler.options[Traveler.selectedIndex].value == '1') {
  alert("Please select your name");
  return false;
 }

 var post = document.getElementById("selectTrip");
 if (post.options[post.selectedIndex].value == '1') {
  alert("Please select a Trip name");
  return false;
 }

  if (document.frm1.PeerNames.selectedIndex==0) {
   msgbox = msgbox + "\n Peer Name - Please select Peer name";
  }

  if (document.frm1.Q1.selectedIndex==0) {
   msgbox = msgbox + "\n Question #1 - Please select your rating for this question";
  }
  if (document.frm1.Q1C.value=="") {
  msgbox = msgbox + "\n Question #1 - Please write a comment for Question1";
  }
  if (obj.value.length < charLimit[0]) {
  msgbox = msgbox + "\n Question #1 - You wrote n characters. Please write at least 50 characters for Question1";
  }

  if (document.frm1.Q2.selectedIndex==0) {
   msgbox = msgbox + "\n Question #2 - Please select your rating for this question";
  }
  if (document.frm1.Q2.value=="") {
  msgbox = msgbox + "\n Question #2 - Please write a comment for Question2";
  }
  if (obj.value.length < charLimit[0]) {
  msgbox = msgbox + "\n Question #2 - You wrote n characters. Please write at least 50 characters for Question2";
  }

  if (msgbox == go) {
   return true;
  }
  else {
 alert(msgbox);
 return false;
 }
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>

<form action="action.asp" name="frm1" method="Post" onSubmit="return ckForm(this);" />
   <select name="Traveler" title="Select Traveler" id="selectTraveler">
    <option value="1">Select Your Name</option> <!-- Get blank row on top -->
    <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
                <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
   </select>


   <select name="TripName" title="Select Peers" id="selectTrip">
    <option value="1">Select a Trip</option> <!-- Get blank row on top -->
     <option value="USA">USA</option>
     <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
</select>
<!-----------------------------------------Evaluation questions ---------------------------------------------->
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Question 1</legend>
   <label for="Question1">Question 1</label>
   <select name="Q1" size="1" title="Select Rating">
    <option></option><option>10</option><option>9</option><option>8</option><option>7</option><option>6</option><option>5</option><option>4</option><option>3</option><option>2</option><option>1</option><option>NA</option>
   </select>
   <label for="Comment1">Comments:</label>
   <textarea rows="3" cols="85" name="Q1C" maxlength="500" minlength="50" title="Comments" id="Question1" class="textarea" /></textarea>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
  <legend>Question 2</legend>
   <label for="Question2">Question 2</label>
   <select name="Q2" size="1" title="Select Rating">
    <option></option><option>10</option><option>9</option><option>8</option><option>7</option><option>6</option><option>5</option><option>4</option><option>3</option><option>2</option><option>1</option><option>NA</option>
   </select>
   <label for="Comment2">Comments:</label>
   <textarea rows="3" cols="85" name="Q2C" maxlength="500" minlength="50" title="Comments" id="Question2" class="textarea" /></textarea>
  </fieldset>

 <p class="submit"><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value=" Submit Form ">&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="reset" name="Reset" value=" Clear "></p>
</form> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, it does not work, ok...can you tell more about it. How isn't it doing what you want ? Validation doesn't work ? Error message doesn't appear ?

Comment: 24th line: missing semicolon @ `var go = msgbox`.

Comment: I updated the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't use javascript to validate the form, and please do never use alert() to deliver a message to the user: it's really annoying. You should use native HTML5 form validation attributes and error messages will be automagically displayed.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Questions</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      textarea {
        display: block;
        margin: 1em 0;
      }

      :invalid {
         border: 1px solid red;
      }

      :valid {
         border: 1px solid green;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>

      <form action="action.asp" name="frm1" method="Post">
        <select name="Traveler" title="Select Traveler" id="selectTraveler" required>
          <option value="1">Select Your Name</option> <!-- Get blank row on top -->
          <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
          <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
        </select>


        <select name="TripName" title="Select Peers" id="selectTrip" required>
            <option value="1">Select a Trip</option> <!-- Get blank row on top -->
             <option value="USA">USA</option>
             <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        </select>
        <!-----------------------------------------Evaluation questions ---------------------------------------------->
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Question 1</legend>
          <label for="Question1">Question 1</label>
          <select name="Q1" size="1" title="Select Rating" required>
              <option></option><option>10</option><option>9</option><option>8</option><option>7</option><option>6</option><option>5</option><option>4</option><option>3</option><option>2</option><option>1</option><option>NA</option>
   </select>
          <label for="Comment1">Comments:</label>
          <textarea rows="3" cols="85" name="Q1C" maxlength="500" minlength="50" title="Comments" id="Question1" class="textarea" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
          <legend>Question 2</legend>
          <label for="Question2">Question 2</label>
          <select name="Q2" size="1" title="Select Rating">
    <option></option><option>10</option><option>9</option><option>8</option><option>7</option><option>6</option><option>5</option><option>4</option><option>3</option><option>2</option><option>1</option><option>NA</option>
   </select>
          <label for="Comment2">Comments:</label>
          <textarea rows="3" cols="85" name="Q2C" maxlength="500" minlength="50" title="Comments" id="Question2" class="textarea" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>

        <p class="submit"><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value=" Submit Form ">&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="reset" name="Reset" value=" Clear "></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I removed your binding function to the form submit event and setted select inputs as required.

Answer (score 1):

The form is submitted if the value of the textarea is more than 50. If not, it will alert and then return false, nothing will happen.

Check your other input element like this too.

```js
function check() {
  var textLength = document.getElementById('textarea').value.length;
  var error = false;
  
  if(textLength > 50){
    error = false;
  } else {
    error = true;
  }
  
  if(error){
    alert("Question #1 - You wrote " + textLength + " characters. Please write at least 50 characters for Question1");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" onClick="return check()" value="Check">
</form>
```

Comment: I just updated the code. I need one JS function to validate all questions, including select drop-down options. When a user click on Submit, the it starts to check. Currently, when i click on Submit button, it goes to action page without any pop up error messages. Thanks.

Comment: It worked for the first question. However, it didn't check for second question. I entered some text on the first comment box. I don't enter anything on second comment box for question #2, but it didn't check. How do I fix your code to work with second coment box. Thanks.

Comment: Your questions is about validation in textarea, I'm not here to solve your whole project. To be honest, I don't even have time to do so. I'm here to help you getting to the solution and in the end it's up to you to take the logic and realize it with the other questions. @JennyTran

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" onkeyup="myFunction()">
   <input type="submit" id="sbm" disabled>
   <p id="para"></p>
 </form>
 <script>
  function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("t1").value;
   var len=x.length
   if(len>5&&len<10){
    document.getElementById("sbm").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = ""; 
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById("sbm").disabled= true;
     if(len<=5){
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "too short"; 
     }
     else{
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "too big";
    }
   }       
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

try this code. easiest way to do it

Comment: Hi Arun, I need a validation for textarea, not input boxes. Thanks.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, same logic can't be applied?